# How to separate comma in js

Tags: javascript

**My input is like the string below:**

```
IN|1st Cross,1st Block,IN|282,Sector 19,IN|10th Floor,Winchester House,DN|id,fgh,FG|ag
```

**What I want should be like:**

```
IN|1st Cross,1st Block IN|282,Sector 19 IN|10th Floor,Winchester House DN|id,fgh FG|ag
```

Please how do I achieve the above result?

Comment: First, help us with more details like which comma has to be removed. There are several commas in your result as well.

Comment: Please format the string and formulate the question well!

Comment: i want only before the country code comma will be remove

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
function separateComaForCountry(str) {
    // find a coma, that has any amount of letters after it that are not , nor | and then stop when you see either the end of the string or another | 
    var reg = /,([^|,]+(?:$|\|))/g;
    return str.replace(reg, function(match, country){
        return ' ' + country;
    });
}
```

Then just call the function with your use case.

```
separateComaForCountry("IN|1st Cross,1st Block,IN|282,Sector 19,IN|10th Floor,Winchester House,DN|id,fgh,FG|ag");
// outputs IN|1st Cross,1st Block IN|282,Sector 19 IN|10th Floor,Winchester House DN|id,fgh FG|ag
```

Comment: Robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to replace the comma before the country code with a space. That is like removing the commas at the 'even positions'.

You can split the string with a comma separator to get the different parts in an array then remove join the entries of the array using the reduce method.

```
const inputStr = 'IN|1st Cross,1st Block,IN|282,Sector 19,IN|10th Floor,Winchester House,DN|id,fgh,FG|ag';

function customStringSplit(inputString){
    const splittedInputStr = inputString.split(','); 

    const resultStr = splittedInputStr.reduce(function(acc, val, index){
        return (index%2 === 1 ? acc + ',' + val : acc + ' ' + val);
    }); 

    return resultStr;
}

console.log(customStringSplit(inputStr));
```

For more insight on the different built-in functions see the [using String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on [Mozilla Developer Network.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)